# Regex - How can I extract a string between two different strings?

Tags: regex, perl

Given the following line:

```
rebeka mecsek:/export/home5/users/rebeka;
```

I'd like to get only the word "mecsek" from the line.
There is a space between the word "rebeka" and "mecsek", and the line beginning with no space.

I tried the following:

```
$homeserver=~s/.*\s//;
```

But I don't want the colon or the part following it, only the word "mecsek".

Could anybody help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$homeserver =~ s/^\S*\s(\S+):.*$/$1/;
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember [Randal’s rule](http://perl.plover.com/yak/regex/samples/slide070.html):

> Randal Schwartz (author of Learning Perl) says:
>
> > Use capturing or `m//g` when you know what you want to **keep**.
> >     Use `split` when you know what you want to **throw away**.

You know what you want to keep, but you haven’t told us everything you know. Do you want the run of word characters following the first space in the line?

```
print $1, "\n" if $homeserver =~ / (\w+)/;
```

Do you want to keep the longest, leftmost string of word characters before `:/`, wherever that happens to be?

```
print $1, "\n" if $homeserver =~ /(\w+):\//;
```

Can we depend on rebeka being at the beginning of the string?

```
print $1, "\n" if $homeserver =~ /^rebeka (\w+)/;
```

If not, is it safe to assume that the beginning of the string will be some contiguous run of word characters?

```
print $1, "\n" if $homeserver =~ /^\w+ (\w+)/;
```

When matching with regular expressions, define your anchors: the features you can rely on being present in the text as markers or bookends for what you want to keep. Also note that the above examples use `$1` inside a conditional only; never use capture variables unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the whole line then:

```
s/[^\s]+ ([^\s+]):.*/$1/
```

Answer (score 0):

I vote for the pattern `/(?<=\S\s)([^\s:][^:]*):/` and the result is in `$1`.